# Using the Kuramoto-Sivashinsky operator applied on the Korteweg–de Vries Soliton as a filter for image processing

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convolution, image-processing

When the Kuramoto-Sivashinsky operator ([Kuramoto-Si](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Kuramoto-Sivashinsky_equation)) is applied to the Korteweg–de Vries Soliton ([Soliton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93de_Vries_equation)) we obtain a very interesting filter which is able to process an image via convolution.

An example is

[image]

Other example is

[image]

Other example is

[image]

Other example is

[image]

Other example is

[image]

Other example is

[image]

Other example is

[image]

Other example is

[image]
Please let me know what would be the advantages of the Kuramoto-Sivashinsky-Korteweg–de Vries filter.

It is possible to introduce the Kuramoto-Sivashinsky-Korteweg–de Vries filter in smartphones (with infrared cameras)  and smart-glasses?

Comment: Do you have a reference for this "Kuramoto-Sivashinsky-Korteweg–de Vries filter", or is it your own idea?

Comment: Hi @Rahul I have not a reference.

Comment: So you want to apply a PDE to a PDE?

Comment: Hi @dustin, I am applying the Kuramoto-Sivashinsky operator to the solution of the Korteweg–de Vries equation.  The resulting filter is applied to an image via convolution using the Maple package "ImageTools".

Comment: What is the operator? I only see it mentioned as a PDE.

Comment: Hi @dustin the operator is extracted from the PDE.